# Do fog and gof uniquely determine f and g?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

If fog and gof are given/known, then are f and g uniquely determined by these? If yes, then how to find them? I am clueless about the general case.

Comment: Sometimes not, for example $f=x+1,g=x+4$ and $f=x+2,g=x+3$

Answer (score 5):

Of course NO! Consider any bijection $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Put $g = f^{-1}$. Then $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are identity maps on $\mathbb{R}$. Clearly we cannot recover $f$ and $g$ by just knowing $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$.